# How can I get my webcam working in kernel 3.9.4 built for ARM?

Tags: linux, webcam, arm

I'm trying to get my USB webcam (Logitech QuickCam Communicate STX) working on an Olimex SAM9-L9260 board (ARM). I have used Buildroot 2013.05 and have the system up and running. I want to take webcam snapshots and trying to use mplayer for this with this command:

> mplayer tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:device=/dev/video0:width=320:height=240 -frames 1 -vo jpeg

This command works in Ubuntu, but not on my embedded board:

> mplayer tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:device=/dev/video0:width=320:height=240 -frames 1 -vo jpeg
>
> MPlayer 1.1-4.7.3 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
>
> Playing tv://.
>
> TV file format detected.
>
> No such driver: v4l2
>
> Exiting... (End of file)

Some start-up lines from the board:

> Linux video capture interface: v2.00
>
> uvcvideo: Unable to create debugfs directory
>
> usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
>
> USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
>
> gspca_main: v2.14.0 registered
>
> usbcore: registered new interface driver gspca_zc3xx

When I connect the webcam to the board a LED in the camera goes on for a short while (same behaviour in Ubuntu) and the terminal prints:

> usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using at91_ohci
>
> gspca_main: gspca_zc3xx-2.14.0 probing 046d:08ad
>
> input: gspca_zc3xx as /devices/platform/at91_ohci/usb1/1-1/input/input0

My Buildroot `.config`:

> BR2_PACKAGE_FFMPEG=y
>   BR2_PACKAGE_FFMPEG_FFMPEG=y
>   BR2_PACKAGE_MPLAYER=y
>   BR2_PACKAGE_MPLAYER_MPLAYER=y
>   BR2_PACKAGE_JPEG=y
>   BR2_PACKAGE_LIBJPEG=y
>   BR2_PACKAGE_LIBUSB=y
>   BR2_PACKAGE_LIBV4L=y
>   BR2_PACKAGE_LIBV4L_V4L2_COMPLIANCE is not set
>   BR2_PACKAGE_LIBV4L_V4L2_CTL=y
>   BR2_PACKAGE_LIBV4L_V4L2_DBG is not set

My Linux kernel 3.9.4 `.config`:

> CONFIG_MEDIA_SUPPORT=y
>   CONFIG_MEDIA_CAMERA_SUPPORT=y
>   CONFIG_MEDIA_CONTROLLER is not set
>   CONFIG_VIDEO_DEV=y
>   CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2=y
>   CONFIG_VIDEO_ADV_DEBUG is not set
>   CONFIG_VIDEO_FIXED_MINOR_RANGES is not set
>   CONFIG_VIDEOBUF2_CORE=y
>   CONFIG_VIDEOBUF2_MEMOPS=y
>   CONFIG_VIDEOBUF2_VMALLOC=y
>   CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2_INT_DEVICE=y
>   CONFIG_MEDIA_USB_SUPPORT=y
>   CONFIG_USB_VIDEO_CLASS=y
>   CONFIG_USB_VIDEO_CLASS_INPUT_EVDEV=y
>   CONFIG_USB_GSPCA=y
>   CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_ZC3XX=y
>   CONFIG_VIDEO_EM28XX is not set
>   CONFIG_V4L_PLATFORM_DRIVERS=y
>   CONFIG_SOC_CAMERA is not set
>   CONFIG_V4L_MEM2MEM_DRIVERS is not set
>   CONFIG_V4L_TEST_DRIVERS is not set

Some V4L files in my board root folder:

```
./usr/lib/libv4lconvert.so
./usr/lib/libv4l
./usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
./usr/lib/libv4l/v4l2convert.so
./usr/lib/libv4l1.so
./usr/lib/libv4l1.so.0
./usr/lib/libv4l2.so
./usr/lib/libv4l2.so.0
./usr/lib/libv4lconvert.so.0
```

What is missing? The camera is detected and I think that I got V4L (ver 1 or 2) support installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! Just had to add "--enable-tv-v4l2" in the mplayer.mk file under "define MPLAYER_CONFIGURE_CMDS"